# Spring data passing param into @Query with specific token

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data

I am using Spring data to query the PostgreSQL DB using @Query and enable nativeQuery = true.

Below is full code:

```js
@Query(value = """ SELECT utb.user_id, (MIN(utb.submitted_date) AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL :timeZoneOffset) AS dateCheck
                               FROM user_table utb WHERE utb.user_id = :userId """, nativeQuery = true)
public List<TimeLog> findAllByUserWithTimezone(
            @Param("timeZoneOffset") int timeZoneOffset,
            @Param("userId") String userId)
```

However i cannot get expected result when try to assign input param timeZoneOffset to :timeZoneOffset on the @Query. Let say if input param timeZoneOffset = 100, then **what i want to get**:

> MIN(utb.submitted_date) AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL '100'

Note on single quotes '100'. However, **what actual value i got** that is:

> MIN(utb.submitted_date) AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL 100

which is no single quotes, causing error in PostgreSQL.

How can i pass single quotes to the query ?. Using single quotes directly on query will NOT work:

> AT TIME ZONE INTERVAL ':timeZoneOffset'

Comment: i think you should get String parameter instead of int

Comment: using String like: @Param("timeZoneOffset") String  timeZoneOffset also not working.